# Histology tissue

Tags: histology, tissue

[image]

Can anybody tell me from where is this tissue taken and in with techique is it colored please ?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! What research have you done before asking it here?

Answer (score 1):

I might as well be wrong, not being an histologist, but that's probably a classic: mammal liver tissue, (poorly) H&E stained, also showing Kupfer cells having phagocytosed something black (carbon particles from indian ink?).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a classic HE stain. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%26E_stain)

Unfortunately I cannot help with identifying the source of the tissue as you have not specified a organism of origin.

Comment: Why did I get down voted? I identified the stain and provided a source. Also I simply pointed out that identification of the source of the tissue may depend on which organism it derives from. Please remember that histology is a broad field and covers both plants and animals! (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histology)